# Algorithm for geometric packing in 2D

Tags: loops, computational-geometry, packing

I want to pack *N* circles in specific packing patterns (hexagonal and square) into a bigger circle with radius *r*, and with number *N* I want to determine minimum required radius *r*.

This is possible in wolfram alpha (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pack+24+circles+in+a+circle&lk=3), but sadly only up to 1,000 circles, after which it only gives out the densest known packing. I'm not completely oblivious when it comes to using MATLAB, so I figured I could create a loop that keeps extending the large circle and filling it up with smaller circles in one of the packing patterns. I just don't know how to form such a pattern in a loop.

Say, start in the center; define big circle *R*, check if it can be filled with a small circle (radius *r*) in all possible directions. Extend large circle when it can't and repeat until *N* circles have been placed.

Comment: I think that "naive" approaches could be simple and already yield good results, but results that are still far from the optimal one. I'm pretty sure that the optimal solutions can not be computed *incrementally*. When you have, e.g. the densest possible packing for 10 circles (in rectangle pattern), then its may be completely unrelated to the densest packing of 11 circles. Naively trying *all* possible packings will not work for a larger number of circles. There are certainly some sophisticated data structures and algorithms involved here...